# Command line MP4 to WMV9 converter

Tags: xna, ffmpeg, mp4, wmv, ms-media-foundation

So XNA seems to need videos in WMV9 format and I have MP4 files. I found a nice tool called ffmpeg but it only supports wmv8 formats. Does anyone know of any tools that are freely available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK to do some programming, not just a tool ready for use out of the box, then Media Foundation sample [`MFSimpleEncode`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mf/archive/2009/12/02/mfsimpleencode.aspx) is perhaps what you are looking for:

> MFSimpleEncode.exe - This is a command line tool that transcodes files
>   from one media format to another. The source code is provided to use
>   as a reference if you write your own transcode application. This tool
>   uses the Media Foundation transcode API, which was introduced in
>   Windows 7.
>
> Examples:
>   [...]
>
> 1. Transcode MPEG-4 to ASF:   MFSimpleencode.exe –i input.mp4 –o output.wmv –p TranscodeProfileASF.xml

Comment: That's perfect from the looks of it. Only needed to compile it. The asf format is the correct output format